# Fix rotation issue of a tile-set and need to get tile-set to lay flat on xz axis

Tags: three.js, 3d, transform, tiles, deck.gl

We have successfully implemented the loading of a tileset for a specific geographic area onto a three.js scene using deck.gl. Then We uploaded that tileset into a three.js scene as a .gltf
However, We have faced an issue with positioning the tileset accurately. It appears to be rotated based on the angle of the globe, whereas we require it to be converted to a flat plane representation.

We did it up to some point following this https://mapscaping.com/how-to-calculate-bearing-between-two-coordinates (But feel like, it is not an optimal solution for our issue).

need to know,

What information do we need to orient them correctly?

are these tiles have this metadata that can help us position them correctly?

Where can we get this data? Does Google provide it?

I need help with this to convert this tile set from a 3d globe ellipsoidal angel to a flat plane (on the xz axis) without any rotation.